# how to call an actionsheet on a bar button item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

yes but i have a problem i have created a controller that inherits from uitableviewcontroller and i have written a code that calls action sheet on barbutton item on toolbar but it gives me an error.

```
mapType = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"MAP TYPE" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(chooseMapType:)]autorelease]; 
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:space, addButton, removeButton,mapType, nil]; [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar]; 

    - (IBAction)chooseMapType:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map Type"  delegate:self   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"     destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:kMapTypeRegular, kMapTypeSatellite, nil];
 [sheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
 [sheet release];
 }
```

this is my method which i have passed to my selector .

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 NSString *clickedButtonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
 if ([clickedButtonTitle isEqualToString:kMapTypeRegular])
 [[self mapView] setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
 else if ([clickedButtonTitle isEqualToString:kMapTypeSatellite])
 [[self mapView] setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
 }
```

this i my action sheet method but it is not getting called and giving me an error that -[UIActionSheet _presentSheetFromView:above:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UIActionSheet. – Abhishek Mar 24 at 8:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure, your **chooseMapType** function is properly connected with **UIBarButtonItem** in your XIB file.

Comment: it is connected properly to xib